# Use GameKit to save data to iCloud with different accounts

Tags: ios, icloud, game-center, gamekit

I was going through the new feature in iOS 8 and noticed the following:

> The new GKSavedGame class and new methods in GKLocalPlayer make it
>   easy to save and restore a user’s progress. The data is stored on
>   iCloud; GameKit does the necessary work to synchronize the files
>   between the device and iCloud.

This is nice, but i'm a little confused. **What if the user's Game Center account and iCloud account are different?**

Also does the user need iCloud drive enabled for this to work?

I searched around and I can't seem to find any information about how Game Center handles this data and how it relates to iCloud.

***Edit***: See this question for more info. [Save game data into iCloud via GameKit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27273072/2158465)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this class was introduced to address the exact issue of

> What if the user's Game Center account and iCloud account are different?

I previously requested an enhancement to Game Center to add "Game Center user specific storage" so that I could track the game state of the Game Center user centrally rather than having to use the iCloud account, which as you say may be different.

So I wonder if this feature is specifically designed to allow you access to the iCloud storage of the Game Center account when it's not the same as the iCloud Account.

I guess unless anyone has experimented with this feature, we may have to wait until Apple "announce" it, perhaps at WWDC 2015?